# Convert column-oriented data to row-oriented HTML

Tags: xslt

My source XML provides data column-by-column; the cells have varying heights. Using XSLT 1.0, I need to pivot this around to match HTML's row-by-row table format.

Example: I need to convert input data like this

```
<source>
    <column>
        <cell height="1">col A row  1</cell>
        <cell height="2">col A rows 2-3</cell>
    </column>
    <column>
        <cell height="1">col B row  1</cell>
        <cell height="1">col B row  2</cell>
        <cell height="1">col B row  3</cell>
    </column>
    <column>
        <cell height="3">col C rows 1-3</cell>
    </column>
</source>
```

into an HTML table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">col A row  1</td>
        <td rowspan="1">col B row  1</td>
        <td rowspan="3">col C rows 1-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">col A rows 2-3</td>
        <td rowspan="1">col B row  2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">col B row  3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How?

**Edit:** Here is another example, one where no single column has as many cells as there are table rows.

```
<source>
    <column id="A">
        <cell height="1">col A row  1</cell>
        <cell height="2">col A rows 2-3</cell>
    </column>
    <column id="B">
        <cell height="2">col B row  1-2</cell>
        <cell height="1">col B row  3</cell>
    </column>
    <column id="C">
        <cell height="3">col C rows 1-3</cell>
    </column>
</source>
```

into an HTML table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">col A row  1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">col B row  1-2</td>
        <td rowspan="3">col C rows 1-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">col A rows 2-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">col B row  3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: JPM: I don't think your edit is well-drfined -- there is no way to decide in which row to put "col A rows 2-3" -- in rows 1-2 or in rows 2-3.

Comment: `col A rows 2-3` has to go in rows 2-3. `col A row 1` is already in row 1.

Comment: JPM: I don't see any logic in this -- `"col A rows 2-3"` is of height 2 and can start either on row 1 or on row 2. Do you use something from the cell contents to determine in which row to put this cell?

Comment: The document order of the XML determines it. The first cell in Column A has height 1. Then comes another cell; regardless of its height, that second one has to start in the next row. Here, that's row 2. If the column's first cell had height 8, then the next cell would start at row 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass1"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vPass1"
   select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMaxRow">
  <xsl:for-each select=
    "$vPass1/*/*/cell/@startRow">
    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>

    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass1">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="pass1"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cell" mode="pass1">
  <cell height="{@height}"
   startRow="{sum(preceding-sibling::*/@height) +1}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
  </cell>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <table>
    <xsl:call-template name="makeRows">
     <xsl:with-param name="pmaxRow" select="$vMaxRow"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="makeRows">
  <xsl:param name="prowNum" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="pmaxRow" select="1"/>

  <xsl:if test="not($prowNum > $pmaxRow)">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "$vPass1/*/*/cell[@startRow = $prowNum]"/>
    </tr>

    <xsl:call-template name="makeRows">
     <xsl:with-param name="prowNum" select="$prowNum+1"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pmaxRow" select="$pmaxRow"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cell">
  <td rowspan="{@height}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<source>
    <column>
        <cell height="1">col A row  1</cell>
        <cell height="2">col A rows 2-3</cell>
    </column>
    <column>
        <cell height="2">col B row  1-2</cell>
        <cell height="1">col B row  3</cell>
    </column>
    <column>
        <cell height="3">col C rows 1-3</cell>
    </column>
</source>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">col A row  1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">col B row  1-2</td>
      <td rowspan="3">col C rows 1-3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">col A rows 2-3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">col B row  3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

This is similar to the XSLT 1.0 solution, but we use the `max()` function and also avoid the recursion by usig the `to` operator.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vPass1">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass1"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vMaxRow" as="xs:integer"
  select="max($vPass1/*/*/cell/@startRow/xs:integer(.))"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass1">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="pass1"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cell" mode="pass1">
  <cell height="{@height}"
   startRow="{sum(preceding-sibling::*/@height) +1}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
  </cell>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $vMaxRow">
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=
          "$vPass1/*/*/cell[@startRow = current()]"/>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cell">
  <td rowspan="{@height}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Dimitre, it took you 3 minutes to come up with that. An hour later, I'm still trying to see how it all works!

Comment: @JPM: The logic is quite simple: `for $k in 1 to max(/*/column/count(cell) return formatRow(/*/column/cell[$k])`  --  we are just "slicing" each column on its kth cell and thus obtaining the kth row.

Comment: Does this depend on at least one column having all cells with height=1? I can't depend on that. I'll add another example.

Comment: In the second example, I don't see how `<xsl:for-each select="column[0+$vLongestColPos]/*">` would produce 3 TRs instead of 2.

Comment: @JPM: this column has three element-children.

Comment: My transformation is happening client-side in a browser, so I can't use extensions, but I'll look at your approach and see if I could make it work.

Comment: Of course you can: `exslt:node-set()` is supported by all browsers excluding IE, for IE use `msxsl:node-set()` in the msxsl namespace: `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`

Comment: Oh. I didn't think browsers had any extensions. Thanks! Would you know where I can find a list of which extensions are in which browsers?

Comment: @JPM: As I said in the previous comment, all but IE should support EXSLT:node-set(). See this: http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.com/2007/05/exslt-node-set-function.html

Comment: Some browsers may support more Exslt functions, but only the node-set() extension function is available in any browser. Of course, one can even use Saxon CE, which allows XSLT 2.0 transformations to be run in any of the 5 major browsers.